# How to insert a hr line between images when the images is going through loos?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to insert a hr line between each pair of image and images is going to show also from loop.

Html--

```
<ul >
                    <li 
                        *ngFor="let image of images"
                        >
                        <div >


                            <img src="assets/img/{{lists.key}}_active.png" alt="Image"
                                class="img-padding font-label1">
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

Expected Outpot

ImageA -----

---

---------  ImageB--------

---

---------Image c

Comment: Have you tried to do it via css `first-child`, `last-child` ?

Comment: No can u explain it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xcudft2s/1/

Comment: this is not a exact soluation for me:i want something like that--->   IA - IB - IC

Comment: If you don't need what has been shown then what else you want?

Comment: in this fiddle line is connected from pictures i just want top give some space from both side